# Howto route in Zend 2 and nginx a route "domain/jobs/index.php"?

Tags: nginx, zend-framework2

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mtg.v4.anwalt.de;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mtg/error.log warn;

    root /opt/mtg/platform/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

and this is the route config i am using:

```
'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'jobs-home' => [
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/jobs/index.php',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => 'jobs-controller-index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Thes result i get is:

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
```

I have this problem only when i have a "index.php" in my route. This is quite a seriuos problem because we have to support old Url's.

And idea would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i changed my config to and it works:-)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mtg.v4.anwalt.de;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mtg/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mtg/error.log warn;

    root /opt/mtg/platform/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
        }


}
```

The problem was this entry: "fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;" that was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a lot of old urls in ZF2 configs, just use nginx redirect directive instead. Try this for any old-way /path/index.php url:

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/index.php$ {    
    return 301 /$1;    
}
```

and then use zf2-way routes (w/o index.php)

```
'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'jobs-home' => [
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/jobs',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => 'jobs-controller-index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

So you will easy redirect old /jobs/index.php by nginx (fast and SEO-effective) to new /jobs and handle it with ZF2.

Comment: Thanks, this is an idea, but i found the real problem: nginx set the $_SEVER['PHP_INFO'] wrong, it should be "/index.php" and not according to my example "/jobs/index.php".